# setCustomValidity no me funciona

Tags: javascript, html

EDITO
El problema es que no se muestra el error del setCustomValidity
He probado varias cosas:
esto lo he metido por que me pedia mas texto (sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)

-He quitado y puesto el pattern

-he realizado lo mismo con addeventlisteners

-He probado con validity.valid dentro y fuera

pero no consigo que se muestre ningún mensaje de error, las validaciones se realizan porque si que cambia de color, si alguien sabe porque que me ayude por favor. :)

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let name = document.getElementById('nombre')
  let pas1 = document.getElementById('password1');
  let pas2 = document.getElementById('password2');

  name.focus();
  pas1.focus();
  pas2.focus();
}

function checkPass() {
  let pass = document.getElementById('password1');
  let passCheck = document.getElementById('password2');
  let reg = /\S{6,}/;
  if (!passCheck.validity.patternMismatch) {
    passCheck.setCustomValidity('joder hermano');

  }
  if (pass.value === '' || passCheck.value === '') {
    pass.style.outline = '1px solid red';
    passCheck.style.outline = '1px solid  red';

  } else {
    if (passCheck.value === pass.value && reg.test(pass.value) && reg.test(passCheck.value)) {
      pass.style.outline = '1px solid green';
      passCheck.style.outline = '1px solid green';
      passCheck.setCustomValidity('');

      console.log(passCheck.validity.valid)


    } else {

      console.log(passCheck.validity.valid)
      pass.style.outline = '1px solid red';
      passCheck.style.outline = '1px solid red';
    }
  }
}
```

````html
```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Registro</title>
  <meta name="description" content="HTML5, CSS3">
  <meta name="author" content="Alejandro Amat">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

<form id="registro" method="post">
    <h1>Regístrate!</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="nombre">Mi nombre es:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Mi email es:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required multiple>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="recuerdame">Recuérdame en este equipo</label>
            <input type="checkbox"  value="true"  id="recuerdame"> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="url">Mi dirección web es:</label>
            <input type="url" id="url" name="url" placeholder="https://ejemplo.com">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password1">Me gustaría que mi password fuera:</label>
            <p>(al menos 6 caracteres, sin espacios)</p>
            <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1"  onblur="checkPass()" required pattern="\S{6,}">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password2">Mi password repetida es:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2"  onblur="checkPass()" required pattern="\S{6,}"  >
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="conocimientos">En una escala de 1 a 10, mis conocimientos de HTML5 son:</label>
            <input type="range" min="1" max="10" id="conocimientos" name="conocimientos">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="fechaInicio">Por favor, inicia mi suscripción el día:</label>
            <input type="date" id="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio" required>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="cantidad">Me gustaría recibir <input type="number" min="0" max="5"  name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="1"> copias de <cite>El manual de HTML5</cite>.</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="tambienCSS3">También regístrame para <cite>El manual de CSS3</cite></label>
            <input id="tambienCSS3" name="tambienCSS3" type="checkbox">
        </li>
        <li>

            <input type="submit" id="registro-submit" value="Envíame">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```
````

Comment: No has puesto el input con id **nombre** y no se puede reproducir bien tu error.

Comment: Por lo que veo siempre el input queda en rojo no?, o sea que no valida

Comment: A mi, en este snippet de código, en pantalla completa, me funciona y me aparece un true en la consola cuando pongo la misma contraseña... ¿donde dices que tienes el error?

Comment: @masterguru lo pusiste tal cual?, a mí me da false.

Comment: bueno, si pones la misma contraseña en ambos campos ami me ha funcionado. Primero la puse mal y me salio false, pero luego la puse igual y me salio true, pero creo que el error es sobre el `setCustomValidity`, que no se como va, es la primera vez que lo veo.

Comment: Igual me da true ahora, me funciona bien

Comment: He actualizado el codigo con todo entero, el problema es que devuelve tu incluso por consola me impreme el mensaje que seteo, pero no lo muestra cuando hago onblur,